# Why is there a discrepancy between ActiveRecord SQL and PL/SQL Developer SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, activerecord

I have a select statement in Oracle PL/SQL Developer that's retrieving values based on a date:

```
select * from <table> where to_date(create_date) = to_date('20090506', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

where `create_date` is of Oracle type date. This returns a non-empty set as it should.  However, in ActiveRecord:

```
<Table>.find_by_sql("select * from <table> where to_date(create_date) = to_date('20090506', 'YYYYMMDD')")
```

returns no rows, which is incorrect.  I suspect it has something to do with how ActiveRecord handles Time/Date/DateTime objects.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your own 'hack' and the column name create-DATE, I suspect create-date to be a DATE column. Oracle is 'friendly' enough to not raise an error when you do to_date of a date column, but it would be better if it did raise an error.
So the correct solution would be (both in ORACLE! as in ActiveRecord):

```
select * from <table> where create_date = to_date('20090506', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

In short: Don't use to_date() on a date column.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my hack.  I'm not proud of it but it'll work.  Any better answers that actually stick to the Ruby/Oracle Date types would be better in my opinion.

```
Table.find_by_sql("
  select * from <table>
  where to_char(create_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2009-05-06'
")
```